# 1644 Price Change Access Denied in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, laravel, mariadb, privileges

I was developing in the normal situation but I needed to export a table from the server and import it to the local database to update my data.

after I imported the table, I got a new error.

```
SQLSTATE[45000]: <<Unknown error>>: 1644 Price Change Access Denied (SQL: update `products` set `weight` = 1560000, `price` = 7320000, `major_shopping` = a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:9:"min_order";i:1;s:14:"discount_price";i:820000;}}, `updated_at` = 2022-06-07 18:52:37 where `id` = 217)
```

I searched and tested many solutions but it didn't fix...

It seems the problem is happening because of privileges, but I can't fix it

Comment: major_shopping looks like a string and so you must put the arg in quotes. like : **`major_shopping` = 'a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:9:"min_order";i:1;s:14:"discount_price";i:820000;}}'**

Comment: @BerndBuffen since this is tagged Laravel that might be a red herring since the Laravel queries use prepared statements and the error messages try to put the parameters in but don't include the quotes

Comment: It doesn't related to laravel, i tried to change the value of price field manually in phpmyadmin, but doesn't grant me and shown exactly the same error

Comment: So you need to grant necessary permissions to the database for your db user. If we talk about the local environment (you mentioned that), I think in most cases it's ok to grant user full access to the database.

Answer (score 0):

It happened because of triggers, I deleted the trigger that a teammate created and it was fixed.
[image]